# What is causing this RVM/bundler discrepancy?

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

Asking RVM to install `ruby-1.9.3-head`, then running `ruby -v` yields `ruby 1.9.3p260`.

Doing a `bundle install`, I get an error `Looking for http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby
-1.9.3-p260.tar.gz and all I got was a 404!`

Looking at the listing of `http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/` I don't see `1.9.3-p260`.

How/why does RVM think head is something that doesn't exist in `http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/`?

In fact, `rvm list known` doesn't even list `1.9.3-p260` as a known Ruby!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you use fresh RVM:

```
rvm get stable
```

then make sure you use ruby:

```
rvm use 1.9.3-head --install
```

you can verify ruby was used with:

```
rvm info
```

currently 1.9.3-head development branch has the patchlevel 260: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/version.h#L2 / https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/b800677425e0839eac1014d0a2fe9201cabe3a18/version.h#L2

Comment: I was already running the most recent RVM (1.15) and I fulle deleted and reinstalled 1.9.3-head. Didn't make any difference.

Comment: but did you at any time run `rvm use 1.9.3-head` ?

Comment: Yes. I have a .rvmrc that does that for the project in question.